# NgxBootstrapIconsModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I just updated NGXBootstrapIcons.

First thing I should say is that as of the lib was built, it was wery difficult to correctly mantain all the imports.
Now by changing to .pick() to .forRoot() it messed up the entire project I was working on.

I followed the instructions and I imported the lib in AppModule with .forRoot(allIcons) and I imported the lib without .forRoot() in the other modules where it needs the component.

Unfortunately I receive this error:
[Link to screenshot](https://prnt.sc/z0817o)
(I cannot post images :) )

This is where I put the library:
[Link to screenshot](https://prnt.sc/z07vpg)

As you can see it should be fine, as the new guide described it.
I don't know why the behaviour is like this.

Comment: From the second image i can see you have imported icon module is other feature modules as well as in app module . And from the first image its suggest only import icon module in app module only . So try with removing icon module from other modules and keep it in appmodule only .

Comment: Yup I noticed that after, i tried changing that but it still don't work